# Vue this.$emit('eventName') events in component A are not triggering this.$on('eventName', callbackFunc) in component B, have I misplaced the handler?

Tags: events, vuejs2, vue-component

Basically, I have components that trigger an event when they are created and a specialized "counter" component that counts the created components, this second component exists in parallel to the first. However when I try to run the app, the counter component only counts itself, it seems to only be detecting the creation event being triggered there.

I've tried to move the this.$on() operation to other lifecycle hooks, such as mounted() but that failed.

Component A:

```
Vue.component('counter-component',{
    template: `
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                Components:
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Count: {{ totalCount }}</p>
                <p>Enabled Count: {{ totalEnabledCount }}</p>
                <p>Diabled Count: {{ totalDisabledCount }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>`,

    created(){
        this.$on('component-created', this.componentCreated),
        this.$on('component-disabled', this.componentDisabled),
        this.$on('component-enabled', this.componentEnabled),

        this.$emit('component-created', 'counter-component');
    },

    data(){
        return {
            totalCount: 0,
            totalDisabledCount: 0,
        }
    },

    computed: {
        totalEnabledCount(){
            return this.totalCount - this.totalDisabledCount;
        },
    },

    methods: {
        componentCreated(data){
            this.totalCount++;
        },
        componentDisabled(data){
            this.totalDisabledCount++;
        },
        componentEnabled(data){
            this.totalDisabledCount--;
        }
    }
});
```

Component B:

```
Vue.component('regular-component',{
    template: `
    <div class="my-2">
        <div class="card" v-show="isVisible">
            This is visible
        </div>

        <div class="card" v-show="!isVisible">
            This is invisible
        </div>
    </div>`,

    created(){
        this.$emit('component-created', 'message-component');
    },

    data: () => {
        return ({
            isVisible: true,
        });
    },

    methods: {
        toggleVisibility(){
            this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;

            if(this.isVisible){
                this.$emit('component-enabled','message-component');
            } else {
                this.$emit('component-disabled','message-component');
            }
        }
    },
});
```

I was expecting both components to be counted, unfortunately only the component that contains the handler.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're expecting there to be a global event bus that you can `emit` and subscribe to.
This is not the case by default in Vue, instead Vue uses a strictly hierarchical approach where events are emitted from child to parent and properties are passed from parent to child. Interaction between sibling components is not intended by default.

A correct approach for your case would be to introduce a parent component that listens for the event, holds the `totalCount` as state and passes it as property to your counter-display component:

```
<parent>
  <regular-component v-on:component-created="totalCount++"/>
  ...
  <counter-component v-bind:count="totalCount"/>
</parent>
```

Comment: Ah, I see, the reason I implemented it in that way is due to it being implemented similarly in this Laracasts tutorial:  

https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/15  

Can I place:   
        this.$on('component-created', this.componentCreated),
        this.$on('component-disabled', this.componentDisabled),
        this.$on('component-enabled', this.componentEnabled),  

In the main Vue component instead of handlind the event in the template?

Comment: That depends on the rest of your code, if your components are direct children of your main it should work, if they are deeper nested it won't.

Answer (score 0):

Use please `vuex`. It helps you to decrease the quantity of spaghetti code.

**https://vuex.vuejs.org/**

Comment: Thanks, but I'm actually just starting with Vue and was hoping to be able to do using Vue events, is there any to do that?